# How to get just element that matches query in a mongo find operation?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, find

i've got some documents like this:

```
{
    "name" : "xxx",
    "address" : " ",
    "mail" : "",
    "url" : "",
    "pos" : {
        "lat" : yyy,
        "lng" : zzz
    },
    "rooms" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("540ce3f8e4b016292085b387"),
            "supplier" : "s1",
            "price" : 41000,
            "details" : [ 
                {
                    "price" : 25200,
                    "key" : "2-1"
                }, 
                {
                    "price" : 15800,
                    "key" : "2-0"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("540ce3f8e4b016292085b3fd"),
            "supplier" : "s2",
            "price" : 44900,
            "details" : [ 
                {
                    "price" : 27000,
                    "key" : "2-1"
                }, 
                {
                    "price" : 17900,
                    "key" : "2-0"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("540ce3f8e4b016292085b53d"),
            "supplier" : "s3",
            "price" : 53500,
            "details" : [ 
                {
                    "price" : 32100,
                    "key" : "2-1"
                }, 
                {
                    "price" : 21400,
                    "keykey" : "2-0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What i need to do is execute a find with some filters AND price range query to fetch just the matching array elements and not all:

This is what i try:

```
var sort  = {};
var query = {name:new RegExp("xx",'i')};
query['$and'] = [{'rooms.price':{$gt:50000}},{'rooms.price':{$lt:100000}}];
var page  = 1;
var ppp   = 20; 

db.collection("myCollection").
  find(query).
  sort(sort).
  skip(page > 0 ? ((page-1)*ppp) : 0).limit(ppp).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    res.send(docs);
  });
```

and i retrieve the same document.

What i need is :

```
{
    "name" : "xxx",
    "address" : " ",
    "mail" : "",
    "url" : "",
    "pos" : {
        "lat" : yyy,
        "lng" : zzz
    },
    "rooms" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("540ce3f8e4b016292085b53d"),
            "supplier" : "s3",
            "price" : 53500,
            "details" : [ 
                {
                    "price" : 32100,
                    "key" : "2-1"
                }, 
                {
                    "price" : 21400,
                    "keykey" : "2-0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I googled about but i find just aggregate or map/reduce element.

I'd like to avoid it.

Is there a good solution??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use aggregate or map/reduce then you could change your data structure.
Extract `rooms` to it's own collection and make sure that every element has id reference to the appropriate document from `myCollection`. This would require at least two query though.

Alternatively, you could filter the content on the application side and not within mongodb.